# Java concept idea

Tags: java, swing, concept

** **SOLVED** **

I'm fairly new to Java and so far I love it!

So I'm just asking if someone has a idea that could help me out. So here's what I would like to do.

What I'm working on right now is a application that can interact with my local website (change titles, content, etc). So what I like to do is show a `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`, and enter a username and password.

So basically if the username or password is wrong I would like to display a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` but when they click `Ok` to let them know that there information is wrong the `showConfirmDialog` disappears!

Any idea guys?! Here's my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class javaTesting extends JFrame {
    public JFrame mrFrame;
    public int enter;
    public JPanel mrPanel;

    public javaTesting() throws Exception
    {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try {
                Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms","root","");
            } catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            mrFrame = new JFrame();
            mrPanel = new JPanel();

            mrPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

            JLabel user = new JLabel("Username");
            mrPanel.add(user);

            JTextField user_input = new JTextField(30);
            mrPanel.add(user_input);

            JLabel pass = new JLabel("Password");
            mrPanel.add(pass);

            JTextField pw_input = new JPasswordField(30);
            mrPanel.add(pw_input);

            mrFrame.setSize(700,700);
            mrFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mrFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //mrFrame.setVisible(true);
            mrFrame.setResizable(false);

            input();

            if(enter == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You clicked ok!");
                input();
            } else {
                System.exit(1);
            }
    }
    public void input()
    {
         enter = (int) JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mrFrame,mrPanel,"Login Cridantiels",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
    public static void main(String agrs[]) throws Exception
    {
        new javaTesting();
    }
}
```

So this is what I did and it seems to work fine for me don't know if its incorrect. However it works :]

```
 do{
        input();

        if(enter == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You clicked ok!");
        } else {
            System.exit(1);
        }
     } while(enter != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: Basically, you need a loop to handle it...

Comment: @shan thanks, I did a do{}while() loop, and it works fine. thanks!

Comment: one more hint. in java all classes should begin with a capital letter :) if you are new, its important to know ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shan has suggested, you need to loop you credentials gathering portion of you code.  Here's an example

```
JPanel pnlDetails = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JTextField userNameField = new JTextField(10);
JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

pnlDetails.add(new JLabel("User name:"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
pnlDetails.add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
pnlDetails.add(userNameField, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
pnlDetails.add(passwordField, gbc);

// The result from the dialog, will be OK or CANCEL
int operation;
// Flag used to determine if the credentials are okay or not
boolean badCredentials = true;
do {

    operation = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pnlDetails, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    String userName = userNameField.getText();
    char[] password = passwordField.getPassword();

    // You would valid you credintals here :P
    if (userName.equals("super") && new String(password).equals("happy")) {

        badCredentials = false;

    } else if (operation != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Credentials", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }

} while (operation != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION && badCredentials);

if (!badCredentials && operation != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {

    System.out.println("Continue program");

} else {

    System.out.println("Exit program");

}

System.exit(0);
```